# Does space in between have any significance in IUPAC nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> The correct IUPAC name of the following compound is:
>
> [image]
>
> (**a**) 2,4,6-trimethyl cyclohexanone
> (**b**) 1,3,5- trimethyl benzophenone
> (**c**) trimethylcyclobutanone
> (**d**) 2,4,6-trimethylcyclohexanone

I was confused between option (**a**) and (**d**). I opted for option (**a**), but our teacher told that ans is an option (**d**). The only difference I see between these two options is that there is space in (**a**). Does space have any significance in IUPAC nomenclature?

Comment: There is no space between substituent prefixes and the parent structure. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Compare "phenyl acetate" and "phenylacetate" – two different compounds.

Comment: How could putting space in the middle of a word **not** make a difference?!

Answer (score 1):

$\boxed{\textbf{d}}$ is correct. It is the standard IUPAC name.

However, "2,4,6-trimethyl cyclohexanone" will often be understood as 2,4,6-trimethylcyclohexanone, similar to how, in theory, neopentane, 2,2-methylpropane and 1,1,1,1-methylmethane are all equivalent.